# Using this in redux initial state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to set certain property of initial state to be relative to other property. So I used `this` inside of it.

```
const initialState = {
  canvas_1: {
    canvasName: "canvas_1",
    top: 500,
    left: 600,
    width: 390,
    height: 800,
    xAxisSnap: [0, this.width / 2, this.width],   <-- here
    yAxisSnap: [0, this.height / 2, this.height], <-- here
    selectedShapes: [],
    children: ["hi"],
  },
};

const canvasSlice = createSlice({
  name: "canvas",
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {},
});

export const selectShapesOnCanvas = (state) => state.canvas.present.children;

export const {} = canvasSlice.actions;

export default canvasSlice.reducer;
```

But this is what I got in return from webpack.

```
var initialState = {
  canvas_1: {
    canvasName: "canvas_1",
    top: 500,
    left: 600,
    width: 390,
    height: 800,
    xAxisSnap: [0, undefined.width / 2, undefined.width],   <-- here
    yAxisSnap: [0, undefined.height / 2, undefined.height], <-- here
    selectedShapes: [],
    children: ["hi"]
  }
};
var canvasSlice = (0,_reduxjs_toolkit__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.createSlice)({
  name: "canvas",
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {}
});
var selectShapesOnCanvas = function selectShapesOnCanvas(state) {
  return state.canvas.present.children;
};

_objectDestructuringEmpty(canvasSlice.actions);


/* harmony default export */ const __WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__ = (canvasSlice.reducer);
```

Am I using `this` the wrong way, or is it not allowed to use `this` in RTK?

Comment: Why do you need to use `this.width / 2 ` instead of `390 / 2` ?

Comment: "Am I using this the wrong way" — Yes. The value of `this` is determined by how the function it appears within is defined and called. It has nothing to do with object literals near where you use the keyword.

Comment: @HanMoeHtet — Writing numbers once makes it easier to maintain code when that number later changes. Writing "Some reference / 2" makes it clear *what* is being devided by 2 which makes the code easier to understand.